# SSH and network applications

Tags: networking, ssh, ip

If I use putty and set up an ssh connection to a remote server through a proxy, and then install a networking application like for example uTorrent, and then tunnle uTorrent through this ssh connection, how would I access uTorrent's web interface what ip should I use? Is it at all possible?

Edit: What I want to do is: I have a pc behind a firewall with a fast internet connection (30MB/s). On this pc I am running a uTorrent. I have ssh'ed and tunnled utorrent to connect through the vps. I want to be able to remotely administarte uTorrent through it's web admin interface. How would I access the web ui through the vps.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, it's called **SSH Tunnelling**. [Here](http://oldsite.precedence.co.uk/nc/putty.html) are some instructions. Basically, to access the web interface, you type in the local ip and port, and set up the port to be forwarded.

Comment: Almost there, it just in that tutorial the client is ssh'ing to server running the application you are trying to access, what I want to do is ssh the pc running the service to a remote vps, and then access this application/service through the vps